# YouTube history not going from mobile phone to the computer

Tags: youtube

I used to watch YouTube videos in a restaurant, and was able to see it in the history when I get home on the MacBook, and watch it again.

For example, I may get a notification on my iPhone, felt interested, and watch it for 5 or 20 seconds. But since the restaurant is too noisy, so I just stop the video and go home and watch it there.

However, today I found even if it is the same account on the iPhone YouTube app and on the Mac's Google Chrome, the history will not transfer from the phone to the Mac.

In fact, the history won't even show on my iPhone's YouTube app history.

I tried to turn off the history of YouTube and turn it back on again, and it won't work.

How do I make it work?

Comment: iPhone anonymization should have nothing to do with my personal YouTube watch history

Comment: This is for iPhone 15 Pro Max, so the YouTube app should be quite current. But I went to the App store to look at the version history, it is like "fixed bug and increased performance, and took an afternoon off by the way" (in Asian language), and "fixed bug and increased performance, and overcome the difficulties of time travel", and "fixed bug and increased performance, and went to the edge of the universe". I am sure it is beyond the level of juvenile.

Comment: If there are additional relevant details you should [edit] the question rather than putting them in comments. Questions about iPhone apps are off-topic on [web-apps.se]

Comment: History syncing in Youtube is tied to your Google account, so of you are logged into the same account on all devices it *should* work. What happens if you add a video to the “watch later” playlist, does it eventually show up in that playlist on other devices?